# Possible phone tapping

Tags: mobile

Only when one of my contacts calls me (my son) when I pick up there is somebody else on the line, usually with a foreign accent. When I hang up and called my son, he confirms he made the call and could hear me talk to him. Strange. Not sure if his dad ( my ex husband) has put some kind of bug on his phone to listen to the conversation. Can not find any answers on Google and I think I am the only person on the planet this is happening to. Has anybody ever heard of this?

Comment: What country is this?

Comment: "crosstalk" is the term to search for

Answer (score 5):

With the old telephone systems which were in use 30..40 years ago such crosstalk happened from time to time. I'm not sure about the quality of the phone system in your place, but this is at least something I've experienced myself several times.

Of course it could be also related to phone tapping but I doubt that somebody who maliciously taps the phone will talk in the background but instead will probably make sure that the tapping is not noticed. I would recommend that you contact your phone company because maybe there is some glitch with your line.

Of course it could still be that really someone is talking in the background, i.e that your son has a visitor.

Comment: It is my cell phone. I did call my cell provider and they claim the problem is on the other end, not mine.

Comment: The voice is from a foreign male, not a child. My son doesn't socialize much.

Comment: I am in the US, East Coast

Comment: I found this on crosstalk: Even in the presence of co-channel interference or crosstalk in the RF system, you can only hear another party's conversation in analog (e.g. AMPS) systems, which are no longer in use in the United States. 

Co-channel interference in GSM can degrade the call quality or cause it to drop, but it cannot let you hear someone else's call.

Comment: If your phone receives somebody else's call over the air due to co-channel interference, timing issues, or any other reason, it will attempt to decrypt the call using a different (incorrect) key, which will not produce any intelligible speech.

Comment: Marta, like Mark asked in your OP, what country are you and your son in?

Comment: United States  East Coast

Comment: Marta: I again recommend to contact the phone company (of your sons phone) and let them find out whats going on. Don't expect too much from this remote diagnosis because contrary to the phone company we cannot watch what is really going on on this line but can only do wild speculations.